# Preimage of Legendre-Fenchel transform

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space with dual $X'$, and let $f : X'\to (-\infty,+\infty]$ be a convex lower semicontinuous function. Does there exist some characterization or some nontrivial results concerning the set of functions $g:X \to (-\infty,+\infty]$ such that the Legendre-Fenchel transform of $g$ is $f$?

Comment: Are you interested in the case that $X$ is not reflexive? I think in the reflexive case one can argue by using the convex envelope.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in the case where $X$ may be nonreflexive, but also reflexive $X$ are of interest.

Comment: In the reflexive case, there are some assertions like "the biconjugate equals the convex lsc envelope", that is the largest, convex, lsc function below your original function. Then, you get all functions $g$, whose convex envelope is the conjugate of $f$. Maybe you can argue similar in the non-reflexive case.

Comment: In the non-convex case it is exactly the same. But I would rather have some more direct statements ..